# Java Swing - JFormattedTextField

Tags: java, swing, validation, jformattedtextfield

I have JFormattedTextField s in my form. I want to validate the length and characters that are being inserted in the field.

e.g FirstName must not allow a length more that 20 characters and should not allow any special and numeric characters being inserted. Space can be considered.

Please help me how can I achieve this goal.

Comment: Is there anything you have tried before asking here? For instance, have you used Google's search engine to look up the documentation for JFormattedTextField?

Comment: You have at least two chocies, you could try using a `DocumentFilter`, see [Implementing a Document Filter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html#filter) and [DocumentFilter Examples](http://www.jroller.com/dpmihai/entry/documentfilter) for more details or try using an `InputVerifier`, see [Validating Input](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/focus.html#inputVerification) for more details

Comment: I have tried setting formatterFactory property to (????????????????????). This does accept only 20 characters. But it is not working properly. When the focus is being changed the text still appears as blank and some white spaces are being inserted automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to validate the length and characters that are being inserted in the field.

Use a `MaskFormatter` with your `JFormattedTextField`. With the MaskFormatter you can:

1. limit the number of characters
2. provide a String of valid characters

Read the API for more information and examples.

Comment: I have been trying to use Mask Formatter for my jFormatterTextField.

MaskFormatter mf=new MaskFormatter("????????????????????");

I want to limit my textfield to accept 20 characters (no numeric and no special).

However if I am trying to enter less than 20 characters the text from text field is getting blank. And blank spaces are being inserted. It does accept only 20 characters. How should I modify my mask?

Comment: @GauravGandhiu,  I don't know how to allow you to enter less then 20. Forget this suggestion. Instead I would go with MadProgrammers suggestion to use a `DocumentFilter`.

Comment: We can set mask formatter to ("**********") so that we can accept less that 20 characters even, and setValidCharacters to alphabets.

It has resolved my issue in very few lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

We can set mask formatter to ("**********") so that we can accept less that 20 characters even, and setValidCharacters to alphabets.

It has resolved my issue in very few lines of code.